# PayPal Checkout with guest checkout error

Tags: laravel, paypal

I already enabled `has active` in the paypal account for guest checkout, the problem is that in the end of the credit card information, it shows the create account paypal form, and obbligates to create a account.

Is there a option to disable it?

To enable the creditcard option i had this option in my code:

```
    <?php 
    return [ 
        'client_id' => env('PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID',''),
        'secret' => env('PAYPAL_SECRET',''),
        'settings' => array(
            'mode' => env('PAYPAL_MODE','sandbox'),
            'AUTHENTICATION_STATUS'=>'X',
            'SOLUTIONTYPE'=>'Sole',
            'http.ConnectionTimeOut' => 30,
            'LANDINGPAGE'=>'Billing',
            'log.LogEnabled' => true,
            'log.FileName' => storage_path() . '/logs/paypal_new.log',
            'log.LogLevel' => 'ERROR',
            'USERSELECTEDFUNDINGSOURCE'=>'CreditCard'
        ),
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

The options you mention are a necessary, not a sufficient condition, for PayPal to display a guest checkout. Other conditions also apply, such as the country of the receiver account and the IP of the buyer account and other client device information, and so PayPal makes its own determinations for every checkout attempt -- so the behavior can vary from buyer to buyer and from test to test. You will need to contact PayPal directly if you need more information, as this is not a programming issue.